# How to shorten references

Tags: writing, writing-style

How to shorten the reference format to maximum one line per reference so that it fits to the guidelines. I have already used APA format. But is there any other format for doing so?

Comment: Can you have a look at how others do it in the same publication?

Comment: Do you mean that you have to fit each reference on one line, but you are not told what format to use? That is unusual.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/87218/which-citation-style-is-the-most-concise-and-has-the-least-impact-on-word-count

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which citation style is the most concise and has the least impact on word count?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/87218/which-citation-style-is-the-most-concise-and-has-the-least-impact-on-word-count)

Comment: I note that, if the answer to @toby544's question is "yes", the proposed duplicate is not a duplicate.  Hence, I voted "needs more details", the details in question being the exact nature of the guideline that OP is trying to follow.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very compact format that is used in this paper:
https://www.science.org/doi/full/10.1126/science.1089072

Here is an extract:

11. J. Ihmels et al., Nature Genet. 31, 370 (Aug, 2002).
12. E. Ravasz, A. L. Somera, D. A. Mongru, Z. N. Oltvai,
    A.-L. Baraba´si, Science 297, 1551 (2002).
13. C. R. Myers, arXiv: cond-mat/0305575 (2003).
14. J. J. Hopﬁeld, Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. U.S.A. 79, 2554
    (1982).
15. D. Bray, J. Theor. Biol. 143, 215 (1990).